# Создать вложенные окна на WinForms

Tags: c#, windows, .net, winforms

Есть ли способ на C# с помощью WinForms сделать такие вложенные окна (как в MMC)?
[image: Вложенные окна в MMC]

Я пробовал в форму добавить еще одну форму:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsTest{
    class Program{
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(){
            var form1 = new Form();
            form1.Text = "Test form 1";
            form1.Width = 500;
            form1.Height = 400;

            var form2 = new Form();
            form2.Text = "Test form 2";
            form2.Width = 300;
            form2.Height = 200;

            form1.Controls.Add(form2);
            Application.Run(form1);
        }
    }
}
```

Но при запуске приложение выдает это:

```
Необработанное исключение: System.ArgumentException: Элемент верхнего уровня нельзя добавлять к элементу управления.
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Form.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
   в WinFormsTest.Program.Main()
```

Comment: @RottenRat да, я не знал как это называется

Comment: попробуйте поискать по winforms mdi, я никогда этим не пользовался, но судя по гуглу должно работать

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нет, это не обычные панели

Comment: Это называется MDI. Открываете любимый поисковик, пишете `WinForms MDI` находите и сторонние библиотеки, и даже [официальную документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-mdi-child-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), а дальше уже выбираете то, что ближе вам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как использовать **MDI** формы в кратце

Создаем форму и кнопку на ней

[image: Форма]

Выставляете параметр **isMdiContainer** в значение **true**

[image: MDI]

Создаете вторую форму. Делайте на ней что угодно

По нажатии кнопки создаем примерно такой метод:

```
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.MdiParent = Form1.ActiveForm;
        form2.Show();
```

Эта форма будет соответствовать Вашим требованиям

Надеюсь это поможет Вам в ваших изучениях!